# Parallel erroring out with `withCallingHandlers`

Tags: r, foreach, try-catch, snow

I have a parallel process that looks like this:

```
library(foreach)
library(doSNOW)

cl = makeCluster(parallel::detectCores() - 1, type = "SOCK", outfile = "out.txt") 
registerDoSNOW(cl)

l = foreach(i = 1:100) %dopar% { 
  res = withCallingHandlers(
    read.csv("somefilethatdoesntexist.csv"), error = function(e) e)
  if(inherits(res, "error")) res = NULL
  res
}
```

My expectation is that even if there is an error in "expression" the loop should continue, but it exits with an error and the resulting "l" variable is not created.

This seems to happen especially related to missing files. But if I'm wrapping it in a tryCatch and handling appropriately within "expression" how can it error out?

Comment: Umm, where is your `%dopar%`?

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example. `res = withCallingHandlers(simpleError("nope"), error = function(e) e)` does not reproduce this for me.

Comment: So, my suspicion is that `fun_that_writes_error_to_file` throws an error.

Comment: Updated with a toy example with a file related error. This fails at task one.

Comment: Substitute `withCallingHandlers` with `tryCatch`?

Comment: Thanks Roland. This led me to the solution, which was to simply wrap withCallingHandlers in a tryCatch (this captures my error with a useful traceback). I would plus one and checkmark it if you want to add it as a solution. I'd still be interested to know why other types of non I/O errors are well handled by withCallingHandlers. I feel like that's unintuitive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this (adapted from [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2005-November/083264.html)):

```
library(foreach)
library(doSNOW)

cl = makeCluster(parallel::detectCores() - 1, type = "SOCK", outfile = "out.txt") 
registerDoSNOW(cl)

l = foreach(i = 1:2) %dopar% { 
  withCallingHandlers({
      res <- withRestarts( read.csv("somefilethatdoesntexist.csv"),
                          skipError=function() return(NULL))
    },
    error=function(e) {saveRDS(e, paste0("E:/temp/", i, ".rds")); invokeRestart("skipError")})
  res
}

l
#[[1]]
#NULL
#
#[[2]]
#NULL

e <- readRDS("E:/temp/1.rds")
e
#<simpleError in file(file, "rt"): cannot open the connection>
```

Comment: Interesting. This is not covered in the documentation. Do you have any idea WHY it works this way?

Comment: I find the documentation too limited as well. Possibly, I'm missing some other official documentation where error catching is explained in more detail? I'm as lost as you are.

Comment: Yet another addition to R Inferno.